# Unexpected token == while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an if/else if statement in my ejs partial file. I want to include only the style part in my main file.
Here's my code:

```
<% if(someVariable == "style"){ %>
    .some-css{
    bottom: -100px;
    visibility: visible;
}
<% } %>
<% else if(someVariable == "code") { %>
    <div class="some-css" > 
some code
</div>
<% } %>
```

In my main file, I included the style like this: `<%- include('partials/nameofFile.ejs',{ someVariable == "style" }) %>`
I get the error:

> unexpected == while compiling ejs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you're trying to include a separate file, you're writing normal JavaScript inside an object where an object only accepts JSON values.

Change your:

```
<%- include('partials/nameofFile.ejs', { someVariable == "style" }) %>
```

To:

```
<%- include('partials/nameofFile.ejs', { someVariable: "style" }) %>
```

Comment: When I ran it again, the error now changes from unexpected token == to unexpected token else

Comment: @tellmeOberlin You haven't included full code in your question therefore I cannot help you. As this answer has solved the question, please click the green tick next to the post to mark it as the correct solution.